# I need a way to find duplicates only when occur simultaneosly in two columns

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, duplicates, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I need a way to find duplicates in google sheets as shown below

[image]

it should be repeating and on both columns on a same row.
Thanks in advance

Comment: find how? with yellow color or with formula?

Comment: some kind of highlighting with some conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF($A$2:$A&$B$2:$B,$A2&$B2)>1)*(A2<>"")
```

[image]